# Authorization header

Tags: http, digest-authentication

I'm using Digest Authentication to check if a user knows the ID and PW of the server. Once the client has entered the server because he knows the credentials (the server has matched its hash response with the hash reponse of the client) all his requests have the Authorization header. Is this normal? The authorization header is not sent only once?

Once the client has passed the Digest Challenge all his requests are like the following (all the requests have the Authorization header):

```
GET /XMLAliasRegDev HTTP/1.1
***Here's the Host***
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://Here's the Host/webpage/html/registry.htm
Authorization: Digest username="xxx", realm="xxx", nonce="b463d286b77fba6535adc1902e43377a", uri="/XMLAliasRegDev", response="4bedc10d3fd7f3fb90ab518ffead238b", opaque="eb2cdfdb6ebd0e78c0737bc4d58d0d3c"
Connection: keep-alive


GET /webpage/scripts/regjs.js HTTP/1.1
***Here's the Host***
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://Here's the Host/webpage/html/registry.htm
Authorization: Digest username="xxx", realm="xxx", nonce="b463d286b77fba6535adc1902e43377a", uri="/webpage/scripts/regjs.js", response="95cd7035c6abf7666fbdb0068aa69b9a", opaque="eb2cdfdb6ebd0e78c0737bc4d58d0d3c"
Connection: keep-alive
```

If the server has matched the responses and the server is sending the resources to the client, why the client is sending the authorization header?
TY!

PS: I'm using Arduino as a server.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this normal?

Absolutely.

> The authorization header is not sent only once?

No, as written in [RFC 2069](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2069.txt) a valid response contains the challenge response. It is then sent in all requests for protected resources in a realm with digest authentication.